# What is the meaning of "e pluribus smart assimus"?

Tags: vocabulary, latin-to-english-translation

I am just curious what a phrase "e pluribus smart assimus" means.

Comment: I am curious: Where did you come across that phrase?

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta Twitch.tv chat :D, someone joked on this topic and everyone seemed like they know what it is all about. I didnt want to look stupid, so I asked here.

Comment: Thanks! Can you edit your question to add that background in? No matter how unreliable, unscientific and unanything it is, the source of the phrase does make a question more interesting.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is dog Latin for "out of many come smartasses" (or "a smartass"). It's modelled off the phrase *ē pluribus unum*, "out of many [comes] one", which is printed on American currency, plus the fake Latin *smart-assimus* for "smartasses". The *-us* is typically a singular ending, but is also commonly used to create dog Latin in general.

---

As a side note, while "smart" of course isn't Latin, *assimus* is a real word: it's the first person plural present active subjunctive of *adsum*/*assum*, "to be present". So *assimus* means "let's go be there!" But that's certainly not what the author of this phrase intended.

Comment: This is right; except why do you translate *smart assimus* as plural? If it's a noun, as it's intended to be, it looks more like a singular (2nd decl.).

Comment: @LarsH Mostly because the plural seems to make more sense in the context of the joke; I'm not sure the writer knew second-declension endings. (If they did, I wouldn't expect *-imus* as the ending at all.)

Comment: Maybe, but a lot of people who know practically no Latin know that -i is the plural of -us in Latin loan words. Also I don't see why the singular makes less sense in the context of this joke.

Comment: @LarsH Fair, added a note

Answer (score 0):

In the "National Sarcasm Society" plate, it's written:
**Like we need your support**

below that, the complement:

E pluribus Smart Assimus

**among so many smartasses**.

See the plate at:
[https://www.amazon.com/National-Sarcasm-Society-Support-Poster/dp/B018F3Y3MY](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B018F3Y3MY)